# Animating an Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I m creating a game, in that i want to use some animation, but i m new to animations.
I want to create an image ,as soon as i click on imageview, the image should come in bouncing manner as if it is a Ball, so is it possible to do so??? The image is predefined for the game.and it must come after touch begin event occures, can any one help me??? 
regards 
viral.

Comment: The answer to this is quite involved. You need to read up on computer animation or game programming.

Comment: If you can imagine it then it can almost certainly be coded, what code have you tried?

Comment: I've not added any animation code, right now i m showing simple value as soon as i touch on the image view, but i want some different image animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like

```
imageview = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)]autorelease];
    imageview.image = [[UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithString:name]]autorelease];
    [self.view addSubview:imageview];
    imageview.frame = CGRectMake(imageview.frame.origin.x, (imageview.frame.origin.y), imageview.frame.size.width, imageview.frame.size.height);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    //[UIView setAnimationWillStartSelector:@selector(Transform2)];


    [UIView setAnimationDuration:k_AnimateTime];

    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    //[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(increaseCount)];
    imageview.frame = CGRectMake(imageview.frame.origin.x - Ex, (imageview.frame.origin.y - Ey), imageview.frame.size.width, imageview.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

this will move your image from one co coordinate to another coordinate animating... set appropriate coordinate to make it looks like bouncing effcet...